# Android Studio(3.5.3(stable) win10) stuck on reference resource file

Tags: android, android-studio

I add line like `background="@drawable/edit_fram"`,then the Ide stuck there for now,it create lot of log , every log start with files.

Comment: did you try reinstaling android studio

Answer (score 0):

Try `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`, it might be the case that some build configurations are conflicting with cache